# Reading a .doc or .docx file in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, .doc

i'm just workin on a project which requires to read word document.
i want to know how to read the *.doc file character by character.... how can i do it?

thanx

Comment: what is the problem ?. When you are asking for a question, please see to that you are giving adequate details so that people can answer the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

A DOCX can be read by using [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&DisplayLang=en)